# How to upload a PDF file from Android?

Tags: java, android, file-upload, multipartform-data

I have followed this [guidance](https://ppolyzos.com/2016/02/07/upload-a-file-to-azure-blob-storage-using-web-api/) to implement a web service to upload files to Azure storage.

I've published it to Azure. It works fine from Postman.

I want to upload PDF files using this service from Android.

The code I last tried was this:

```
new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, url)
      .addFileToUpload(file.getAbsolutePath(), "file", file.getName(), ContentType.APPLICATION_PDF)
      .addParameter("name", file.getName())
      .setDelegate(new MyUploadStatusDelegate())
      .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
      .setMaxRetries(0)
      .startUpload();
```

**This resulted in a 400 response**, but I've tried several variations with mixed results.

I've had a debugger attached so I know the web service is being called. I can't debug at the moment so can't say what's happening on the server with this version of the call.

I'd appreciate any help in getting this Android code working. My head is hurting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is wrong with the code I posted, but after looking at the source code of addFileToUpload I could see that if content type was null it would work it out for itself. I did that and hey-presto it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            //Creating a multi part request
            new MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, UPLOAD_URL)
                    .addFileToUpload(path, "f_url") //Adding file
                    .addParameter("category", "file")
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token) //Adding token
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload(); //Starting the upload

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            Toast.makeText(this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```